# how to showing a div tag when select a checkbox

Tags: javascript, css

I have a checkbox that I want to display a div tag when I check it ...

My CSS for my `div` in the regular state is :

```
.bookInfo {
width: 0px;
font-size: 2em;
height: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-transition: height 2s, width 2s;
-moz-transition: height 2s, width 2s;
-ms-transition: height 2s, width 2s;
-o-transition: height 2s, width 2s;
transition: height 2s, width 2s;    
}
```

I want when I check the checkbox it becomes :

```
width: auto;
height: auto;
-webkit-transition: height 2s, width 2s;
-moz-transition: height 2s, width 2s;
-ms-transition: height 2s, width 2s;
-o-transition: height 2s, width 2s;
transition: height 2s, width 2s;
```

My checkbox and div tag :

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="bookList" value="book2" id="bookList_2">

  <div class="bookInfo" id="infoBox">
testetstetwtasdljas;ilsajdlaisjdiasjdiaojwiejasdjlsjd<br>
testetstetwtasdljas;ilsajdlaisjdiasjdiaojwiejasdjlsjd<br>
testetstetwtasdljas;ilsajdlaisjdiasjdiaojwiejasdjlsjd<br>
testetstetwtasdljas;ilsajdlaisjdiasjdiaojwiejasdjlsjd<br>
  </div>
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the css adjacent sibling selector (CSS2.1)

It will work as of Internet Explorer 7:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + .bookInfo{
    /* Your styles when cheked /*
}
```

So you css would be :

```
.bookInfo {
    width: 0px;
    font-size: 2em;
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: height 2s, width 2s;
    -moz-transition: height 2s, width 2s;
    -ms-transition: height 2s, width 2s;
    -o-transition: height 2s, width 2s;
    transition: height 2s, width 2s;    
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + .bookInfo{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

(You don't need to specify the transition properties several times)

http://caniuse.com/css-sel2

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/checked/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
CSS

```
.bookInfo {
width: 500px;
font-size: 2em;
height: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-transition: height 2s, width 2s;
-moz-transition: height 2s, width 2s;
-ms-transition: height 2s, width 2s;
-o-transition: height 2s, width 2s;
transition: height 2s, width 2s;    
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="bookList" value="book2" id="bookList_2">

  <div class="bookInfo" id="infoBox">
testetstetwtasdljas;ilsajdlaisjdiasjdiaojwiejasdjlsjd<br>
testetstetwtasdljas;ilsajdlaisjdiasjdiaojwiejasdjlsjd<br>
testetstetwtasdljas;ilsajdlaisjdiasjdiaojwiejasdjlsjd<br>
testetstetwtasdljas;ilsajdlaisjdiasjdiaojwiejasdjlsjd<br>
      </div>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById('bookList_2').onclick = function(){
    if(this.checked){
        document.getElementById('infoBox').style.height = '200px';
    }
    else{
      document.getElementById('infoBox').style.height = '0px';
    }
}
```

Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hicurin/5wcK5/)

Comment: transition will not applied with this way ... not ?!

Comment: It seems like the OP needs class change on click. Update you answer.

Answer (score -1):

In the head section of your HTML:

```
<script type="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bookList_2').click(function() {
        $('#infoBox').toggle();
     });
});
</script>
```

Comment: it's based on jQuery..you should link the jQuery at first:)

Comment: My solution does not need javascript. @hicurin +1 the question ;-)

Comment: @user3104183 +1 the question ;-) Amir needs reputation!